# Adding custom HTML pages using war overlay in jenkins

Tags: maven, user-interface, jenkins, war, jelly

I am trying to add a new html page using war overlay.
I was able to change the favicon.ico using this approach.But I am not able to add a new html page(say like home.html)

I added using the below structure [image]

Now on loading my war, which contains the jenkins as dependency, the new html page is getting loaded .But i am not able to communicate to any of the existing pages of jenkins.

I wanted to have a link from this home.html page to the jenkins pages.

Comment: What do you mean by "But i am not able to communicate to any of the existing pages of jenkins." ?